# jquery a new question mark is added when submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form and i want to submit it to a webservice,

i tried this:

```
if (errorCount == 0) {
    var mobileNumber = $("#iMobileNumber").val();
    var password = $("#iPassword").val();
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/test2/eattel/customers/loginWeb/" + mobileNumber + "/" + password, $('#fLogin').serialize(), function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

but when i submit the form i just get the old url + question mark.

what am i doing wrong please?

thanks in advance

#### Edit

i can alert the password and the mobilenumber so the code is exclusive correctly

Comment: Show us how you are running the above code.

Comment: @Blazemonger they run and I can alert the mobile and password values

Comment: @marco why is this question not tagged javascript?

Comment: @JanDvorak i just edit it and added the javascript tag

Comment: please why would you downvote this question? i had a problem, i tried to solve it. i give you what i have tried and i asked for helping in a specific thing. so i didn't make any mistake againt the policy of stackoverflow

Comment: the people who downvote may be doing so because they think this question is not useful for the site. At least one person also thinks this question is not clear enough.

Comment: @JanDvorak i can understand it is not a perfect question, but i am a biggener and i tried to solve a problem, i really tried but i have a problem so i deserve an answer ,, right?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code the url is like

```
http://localhost:8080/test2/eattel/customers/loginWeb/mobileNumber/password
```

so try the below thing

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/test2/eattel/customers/loginWeb", mobileNumber + password, $('#fLogin').serialize(), function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
```

Comment: still the same, but please i want the password and the mobie in the url

Comment: @marco having the password in the url is a terrible idea in terms of security

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli  yeah  why you want password in url better send them as data using jQuery post!

Comment: please i am just trying, it is practicing and nothing serious